# How can I cut out a section of a circle using Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape I first typed text, created a circle, then made two lines from the center.
It looks like this now:

[image: image 1]

Now, I want it to look like this with the piece cut off, which I made before:

[image: image 2]

I can't make it work. Every path boolean operation is not working.
How do I cut circle like a pie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick is to make lines go considerably out of the circle like this: [image: lines crossing the circle] For some reason it doesn't work if they cross just a little.
Then you select both of the triangle and circle then do the Path>Division and you'll get this:[image]
Of course, triangle is one path with three nodes, not two lines.

Answer (score 13):

- Draw your text and a circle and center them on the vertical axis.
- Draw a *closed* triangle over the "X". It can be curved but it must be closed.
- Convert the circle in to a path
- Duplicate the circle and the triangle
- Select one of the triangles and move it to the top z-index
- Shift-select one of the circles
- Invoke the "Path" -> "Cut Path" menu item
- You should now have an arc of the circle cut away
- Edit the triangle path and create nodes where the triangle meets the circle.
- Select the nodes you just created and break the path using the toolbar button
- Now select the circle arc and the triangle path
- Invoke the "Path" -> "Combine" menu item
- Lastly, join the nodes where the triangle meets the arc using the toolbar button
- You can now fill the section and move it.

See Also: http://inkscape.org/doc/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html

Comment: I tried, but circle is already path

Comment: I'll change my answer shortly with detailed steps for the method I am using.

Comment: I've amended my answer, let me know if that is not clear

Comment: i was trying your answer and then found out where is the trick

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is 'exclusion' which is in the path menu about 7 items down:

1. make big circle (say red)
2. make shape object to delete from it (say grey)
3. put grey object over red object
4. select both with mouse
5. use exclusion

This is how I make the 'doughnut' in a 'no' symbol (aka circle slash)

Comment: This actually worked for me, while the path cutting did not. Exactly what I needed, thanks.